# finding most probable region in random matrix

Tags: python

I spent days struggling with what should be a simple problem...

I have 100 thousand 11x11 matrices. I want to know in which area of these matrices it is more likely that the data concentrates. As my data is noisy I use a sliding window of 3x3, and for each of my 100K matrices, I keep the coordinates of the sliding window that sums more counts. At the end I visualize in which part of the matrices I found more counts.

Here is an example of code to reproduce the problem:

```
from random import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

size = 11

positions = np.zeros((size, size))

for _ in range(100000):
    matrix = [[random() for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
    max_value = 0
    max_coord = 0, 0
    for beg in range(1, size - 1):
        for end in range(1, size - 1):
            suma = sum(matrix[i][j] 
                       for i in range(beg - 1, beg + 2) 
                       for j in range(end - 1, end + 2))
            if suma >= max_value:
                max_value = suma
                max_coord = beg, end
    positions[max_coord] += 1

plt.imshow(positions[1:10,1:10], origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
```

In the example I use random matrices (I have used different kind of random generators), and a window size of 3x3 (same result with 2x2, 5x5 etc.. Hopefully not with 1x1).

My problem is that, as I am using random matrices as input, I expect to have a random final matrix, but I got this:

[image]

The distribution of values is like:
[image]

I know this looks like a stupid mistake in the code, but I really run out of ideas.

**EDIT**

just in order to avoid repeating analysis:
 What I have tried so far (in **bold** the one in the example above):

- window sizes:

  - 1x1 (working)
  - 2x2 (not working -> similar to above)
  - **3x3** (not working -> similar to above)
  - 5x5 (not working -> similar to above)
- window step:

  - **1** -> overlapping (not working)
  - 2 -> not-overlapping (not working)
- randomization

  - **random.random**
  - lognormal
  - binomial (n=100, p=0.2 and p=0.5)

  **EDIT 2**

@jhc is right it is a probabilistic effect, my solution to circumvent the problem is to use non overlapping windows. Example result:

[image]

... not as nice but at least correct :)

**EDIT 3**

I posted a follow-up question in https://math.stackexchange.com in order to know if this bias can be modelled: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281256/bias-in-getting-submatrix-of-higher-sum-in-random-matrices

Comment: I think the way way you handle the borders of your matrix is not right. This is where lays the error

Comment: Is this not just to do with the fact that your 3x3 window doesn't have 9 elements in the corners and at the edges?

Comment: Could you do something like multiplying the counts at the corners by 9/4 and those at the edges by 9/6? Might have to think about the probabilistic implications but it should make everything the same magnitude at least

Comment: (also I definitely wouldn't recommend using an even number window that will cause problems)

Comment: @bhc no, i only count internal cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a probabilistic effect. Your result having higher values in the 3x3 submatrices in the corners correlates negatively with the sample rate of individual cells.

You can think of it as the probability of a single cell to propagate its value to the 3x3 submatrices around it. A very high (or low) value in a corner (e.g. [0,0]) will affect only to the 3x3 submatrix represented at [1,1]. Values in the inner parts contribute to more 3x3 submatrices. With enough repetitions, this effect creates the observed gradient, which is not only present for maximum values, but also for minimum values.

check this code calculating the sampling rate of each cell:

```
from random import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
size = 11

positions = np.zeros((size, size))
visits = np.zeros((size, size))

for i in range(1000):
   matrix = [[random() for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)]
   max_value = 0
   max_coord = 0, 0
   for beg in range(1, size - 1):
       for end in range(1, size - 1):
           suma = 0
           for i in range(beg - 1, beg + 2):
               for j in range(end - 1, end + 2):
                   suma += matrix[i][j]
                   visits[i,j] += 1
           if suma > max_value:
               max_value = suma
               max_coord = beg, end
   positions[max_coord] += 1

#plt.imshow(positions, origin='lower')
plt.imshow(visits, origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: cellvisits]